# Python - fill the gap between two values in a list by the the second value

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
lst = ['a','a','a','X','y','y','y','a','a','y','y','a','a','a','a','a','a','X','y','a','y','a','y','y','y','a','a','a','a']
```

The mission is to get this output

```
lst = ['a','a','a','X','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','a','a','a','a','a','a','X','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','a','a','a','a']
```

Explain: Simply, find X and the last y before the next X  and then replace the values of a in between by y. If there is no next X at the end then consider the last y.

What I have tried is to find the starts and ends indices

```
starts = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == 'X']
```

[3, 17]

```
ends = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == 'y']
```

[4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24]

and then loop on starts to find the numbers between 3,17 within ends, and then take the max and replace from 3 to the max which is 10 in this case. And so on.

The question is there any better way than this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The input is always strings?

Comment: yes, it's actually words and characters. I just tried to simplify.

Comment: What would be the output for ['X', 'a', 'y']? ['X', 'y', 'y']?

Comment: Exactly!, but there are some other scenarios. like the example above.   ['X', 'a', 'y','a','X', 'a', 'y'] ==> ['X', 'y', 'y','a','X', 'y', 'y']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def fill_gap(l, pivot='X', target='a', fill='y'):
    result = l[:]
    X_indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(l) if e == pivot] + [len(l)] # find the indices of pivot
    for start, end in zip(X_indices, X_indices[1:]): # iterate over the slices from the indices of pivot
        segment = l[start + 1:end]
        try:
            ye = len(segment) - 1 - segment[::-1].index(fill) # find the las appearance of fill if exists 
            for j, e in enumerate(segment):
                if e == target and j < ye: # if equals target and if before the last appearance of fill
                    result[start + 1 + j] = 'y'
        except ValueError:
            continue

    return result


lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'X', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'X', 'y', 'a', 'y', 'a',
       'y', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
print(fill_gap(lst))
print(fill_gap(['X', 'a', 'y']))
print(fill_gap(['X', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'X', 'a', 'y']))
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'X', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'X', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
['X', 'y', 'y']
['X', 'y', 'y', 'a', 'X', 'y', 'y']
```

Note that the function `fill_gap` returns a new list (`result`), but this can be easily change to modified the list in-place.